# When a bash script lists correspond file in directory, but not working properly?

Tags: bash, shell, glob

When I try to get file list with some rule.

```
[rtrs@10.10.12.12:~]
$ for x in ./*;do echo $x; done;
/home/mariolu/out_protocol
/home/mariolu/proto
/home/mariolu/proto2
/home/mariolu/protocol_build.3.6.1.sh
/home/mariolu/protocol_build.3.6.sh
/home/mariolu/replace_pb_lite_runtime.sh
```

It works.

When I list only `.sh` files. It also works.

```
[rtrs@10.10.12.12:~]

$ for x in ./*.sh;do echo $x; done;
/home/mariolu/protocol_build.3.6.1.sh
/home/mariolu/protocol_build.3.6.sh
/home/mariolu/replace_pb_lite_runtime.sh
```

But I try to list only `.proto` files. It does not work properly.

```
[rtrs@10.10.12.12:~]
$ for x in ./*.proto;do echo $x; done;
*.proto
```

Bash treats `$x` like string `*.proto`. But here intention is that `$x` is a empty list and code breaks from "for loop".

Comment: In Bash you need `shopt -s nullglob`. See `man bash` and look for `nullglob`.

Comment: You can also use `shopt -s failglob` if you want to raise an error instead of getting a (silent) empty result.

Comment: In general I tend to avoid modifying shell behavior with `shopt` because it may break other piece of code that you have. In this case I would use `find` but you need a complex syntax to use it properly, so you may not like.

Comment: Your first `for` loop could not possibly brint what you claim it prints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I frequently use `shopt` in scripts, but when you don't want to, you should explicitly test the result.

You can test for the glob string itself -

```
for x in *.proto;
do [[ "$x" == '*.proto' ]] && continue
   echo $x
done
```

but '*.proto' is actually a valid filename, so it's possible it could get created and this would skip it. That might be a bug or a feature, depending on your needs.

Another approach is to test if the filename actually exists.

```
for x in ./*.proto;
do [[ -e "$x" ]] && echo $x
done
```

This *will* include any file literally named `*.proto` if it exists...